# How to assign field name dynamically to list of sobject to check and assign value?

Tags: apex

I have a metadata stored in a map as

```
Map<String, Contract_Aggregate_Fields__mdt> mapCMD = Contract_Aggregate_Fields__mdt.getAll();
    map<string,string> mapofFields = new map<string,string>();
    for(String keySetString : mapCMD.keySet()){
        mapofFields.put(mapCMD.get(keySetString).Field_Name__c,mapCMD.get(keySetString).Contract_Product_Field_name__c);
    }
```

I have list of records(lstcontractProd) over which am iterating.

```
for (i = 0; i < lstcontractProd.size(); ++i) {
        
      for(String key: mapofFields.keySet()){
          String s = mapofFields.get(key); //s contains the field name which i need to use below
          
         integer count = 0;
         for (j = 0; j < lstcontractProd.size(); ++j) {
            if (lstcontractProd[j].s == lstcontractProd[i].s) //here am getting variable  s does not exist.
            ++count;
         }
```

If I hardcode the field name I am able to use it. How to use this dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `get` to dynamically access a field:

```
if (lstcontractProd[j].get(s) == lstcontractProd[i].get(s)) {
```

Note that `get` will return values as *objects*, so if you're concerned about case-insensitive values, etc, you might need to use a more complicated solution, such as checking the data type and branching off depending on the type of data you have, or at minimum, perhaps some string conversion:

```
if (''+lstcontractProd[j].get(s) == ''+lstcontractProd[i].get(s)) {
```

Which will probably, more or less, do the right thing for most data types (but be aware that you can end up with `null` becoming `'null'`, which might cause other issues).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, this worked.